# Camunda jump to next user task

Tags: javascript, camunda

I am attempting to string tasks together, I am able to get the task ID of the next user task by running the following in a TaskListener Create script:

```
var system = java.lang.System;
system.out.println(task.id);
```

Which returns the correct id.

I would then like to update the url in the browser to "ip:port/camunda/app/tasklist/default/#/?task=" + task.id

But because the TaskListener Create script is not running in the browser itself (not sure why to be honest), I don't have 'window.location' available.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested we found a solution.

We use the REST api's GET task command, the code looks like this

```
camForm.on('submit-success', function() {
inject(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var user = $rootScope.authentication.name;
  setTimeout(function(){  
    $.get("/engine-rest/task?sortBy=created&sortOrder=desc&assignee=" + user, function(data) {
      window.location.replace("http://is-company.intelligentsystems.lan:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/#/?task="+ data[0].id);
   });
  }, 300);
}]);
});
```

This code is called when you press start/complete on a task, and the processing is successful (*submit-success*), then it finds the current user, and searches for the newest task assigned to the user and sets it in the url using *window.location.replace*
We had the issue that the task is not completely created when the code is run immediately, but adding a small delay of 300 (could be smaller, but better safe than sorry) before getting the task id.

Answer (score 1):

Any script that you add to your process model is executed on *server side* (including task listeners), unless it belongs to a task form.

The `task` object is an instance of the Java class `org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateTask`. You can skip the current task by writing `task.complete()`.

Links:

- https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.7/org/camunda/bpm/engine/delegate/DelegateTask.html
- https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.7/org/camunda/bpm/engine/delegate/DelegateTask.html#complete()

Comment: I realized (right after posting) that the script was run on the server side, but setting the task to complete would not solve my issue.
I am trying to somewhat seamlessly go from one usertask to the next without having to do multiple clicks in between (user tasks are auto-assigned to the user who started the process).